# How to use sed or awk to extract substring

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file that contains the following:

```
[class:ABC_DEF_GHI]
[class:ABC_DEF_GHI:app:ABC_DEF_GHI]
```

My goal is to extract ABC_DEF_GHI

Here is the script I'm trying to write so far.

```
eval sed -n 's/.*app://p' file.txt >> $file
```

Comment: Expected output please.

Comment: Use `grep -Po ':\K[^:]+(?=]$)'`

Comment: Your requirements are unclear: the files has 3 equal substrings `ABC_DEF_GHI`, which one do you want? Your own solution suggets the last one and should work when you remove `eval` (or improved with a match on an additional `:` with `.*:app:`).

Comment: Yes, there are three substrings that are the same. I just need one. I just chose the second line because I found it easier. My solution extracts ABC_DEF_DHI], but I want to cut the last character ']'. Can you please help me with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this value by using multiple delimiters in `awk`:

```
awk  -F':|]' '{print $2}' $file
```

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/.*:(.+)]/\1/' file
ABC_DEF_GHI
ABC_DEF_GHI
```

extract content between a colon and right square bracket, due to greedy match it will be the last colon.